# NullReferenceException When Calling Method From Another Class

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, methods, nullreferenceexception

I've got two classes, one called Simulation, another called Star shown below:

```
public class Simulation
{
    public static Simulation simulationInstance;

    public void test()
    {
        Debug.Log("test");
    }
}

public class Star
{
    public void test2()
    {
        Sim.simulationInstance.test();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the test() method in Simulation from the test2() method in Star.

But this returns an error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

Pointing to this line:

```
Sim.simulationInstance.test();
```

What am I doing incorrectly, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you never instantiate `simulationInstance`. You should do that like this:

```
public class Simulation
{
    public static Simulation simulationInstance = new Simulation();

    ...
```